# weekly series calculation with php if statement

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, time-series

I am a little *array-ed* out with this and I am hoping that someone can help me.  I have a few variables and am a little stuck with using the arrays in an if statement.

What I like to find out is if my relocation_date is less then notified_time (from a generated series) then give me old_meter_id else meter_id

```
$meter_id         = 1393;
$notified_time   = '2013-05-01 09:53';
$completed_time  = '2013-05-01 11:52';
$relocation_date = '2013-04-24 00:00';
$old_meter_id    = 1832;

$notified_time   = strtotime($notified_time);
$completed_time  = strtotime($completed_time);
$relocation_date = date($relocation_date);

$combined   = array();

for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
{       
    $start_series = strtotime("- $i weeks", $notified_time);
    $end_series   = strtotime("- $i weeks", $completed_time);

    $combined[] = array( 'start_time'   => date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$start_series), 
                         'end_time'     => date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$end_series), 
                         'relocation'   => $relocation_date,
                         'meter_id'     => $meter_id,   
                         'old_meter_id' => $old_meter_id,   
                         );
}
```

sample expected output to be like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 01-05-2013 09:53:00
            [end_time] => 01-05-2013 11:52:00
            [relocation] => 2013-04-24 00:00
            [meter_id] => 1393
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start_time] => 24-04-2013 09:53:00
            [end_time] => 24-04-2013 11:52:00
            [relocation] => 2013-04-24 00:00
            [meter_id] => 1832
        )

.....
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check it in the loop like

```
for($i=0;$i<=10;$i++)
{       
    $start_series = strtotime("- $i weeks", $notified_time);
    $end_series   = strtotime("- $i weeks", $completed_time);
if(strtotime($relocation_date) < $start_series){
    $combined[] = array( 'start_time'   => date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$start_series), 
                         'end_time'     => date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$end_series), 
                         'relocation'   => $relocation_date,
                         'meter_id'     =>$old_meter_id,                                
                         );
}else{
    $combined[] = array( 'start_time'   => date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$start_series), 
                         'end_time'     => date('d-m-Y H:i:s',$end_series), 
                         'relocation'   => $relocation_date,
                         'meter_id'     =>$meter_id,                                
                         );
}

}
```

Hope this is the solution you are looking for